# Roblox Script only works onetimes

Tags: roblox

I'm working on a script that change your team and open a Gui when you die, but it only work onetime.

Here is my script, I put it into `ServerScriptSevice`:

```
game:GetService('Players').PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character)
character:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Died:connect(function()
        
 local gui = player.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("TeamGUI"):WaitForChild("Background") 

        player.TeamColor = game.Teams:findFirstChild("Choosing").TeamColor
        
        wait(3)

        gui.Visible = true
                
        end)
    end)
end)
```

I don't know why but only the Teamcolor works several times and the Gui once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because your event works only when player joins

your script works like:
Player joined **AND** died then gui appears

you need to do:

Player Joined **OR** Dies

like this in LocalScript

```
local plr = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer
plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function() -- when character loads (Player Joins or Die) your gui should appear
   local gui = player.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("TeamGUI"):WaitForChild("Background")
   plr.TeamColor = game.Teams:findFirstChild("Choosing").TeamColor
   wait(3)
   gui.Visible = true
end)
```

try this, if its not work then comment

Comment: where should i put the LocalScript in?

Comment: in StarterPlayer -> StarterPlayerScripts

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Idk if this is important but i have also a LocalScript in the Background Frame. It's open the frame even if it's invisible in workspace

Comment: its because i of "local gui = player.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("TeamGUI"):WaitForChild("Background")"
i haven't added "player" variable, change "player" to plr

Comment: i did it but nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

here try this, it should work

```
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer    
local character = plr.LocalPlayer.Character or plr.LocalPlayer.CharacterAdded:Wait()

character.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
  local gui = plr.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("TeamGUI"):WaitForChild("Background")
  plr.TeamColor = game.Teams:FindFirstChild("Choosing").TeamColor
  wait(3)
  gui.Visible = true
end)
```

basically what I did was set up an event that listens for whenever your character has died

Comment: I put it into ServerScriptService but it's not working. I also tryed to put it into StarterPlayerScript but the same result

Comment: any errors? also this script is meant to be put in starterplayerscripts

Comment: I found one it says:  LocalPlayer is not a valid member of Player "Players.Ichbindubist123" (Ichbindubist123 is my name)

Comment: Ok i found out it's working. Thanks for the help